Choosing value to prioritize in output display after one-to-many spatial join in ArcGIS Pro
I am currently taking Fundamentals of GIS course on Coursera through UC Davis. For our Assignment 2 I am running into something confusing (Step 5.1-5.2) that I have seen multiple other questions about online (on the course discussion forum and other forums) without any responses/solutions.
In the assignment, we are using data on California watersheds/streams and surrounding soil types. I took a previously created layer that was a 100m buffer of my desired selected streams/rivers, and completed a spatial join with a layer of soil data with the desire to determine the soil drainage for each segment of the river buffer. In the resulting output layer, because during the spatial join in step we were instructed to set the join operation parameter to 'one to many', many of the stream sections in the output feature class have duplicate features: one for each soil drainage type that the section overlapped with.
So in the output layer (included below), all I am currently seeing is the 'well drained' symbology because all of the stream sections overlapped with some amount of well drained soil and i guess that is just what the program is showing on top of the other values. However if I used the interactive select tool to select a polygon segment from the new spatial join layer with the attribute table open, i see that there are almost always multiple features associated with any given segment, often with different soil drainage types.
I have discovered that by dragging the different values up/down to re-order them in the symbology tab, this will affect which value is displayed with priority in the map view. This is how I was able to get a map that showed different values, even though it doesn't seem like the most accurate solution because I don't know which soil types should be shown with priority in this case. However, the instructor did not address this at all in the directions & his map shows the different symbology values in the default order while still displaying the varied values.
Why is this and how do I know which value to prioritize in the display for each polygon segment if there are multiple overlapping values present?
How do I set this up within ArcGIS Pro?
I have included an image of my map (before changing the display order).


I would have run some sort of overlay (e.g. Intersect) of the buffer and soil types and symbolized the result.  If you needed relative soil types per stream segment you could (after recalculating area fields) run a pivot table and join the results back to your stream segments to get what you want to symbolize or more simply dissolve on the buffer overlay segments and choosing your preferred statistic parameter for symbology.

Above comment for area calculation if that is priority, otherwise can prioritize based on the join count if number of occurrences matter, but either way would require an arcade label expression to set symbol class rather than just a field based unique value symbology from layer categories.
This could be rather robust but involved in the expression builder and you would use expression button next to field drop down in unique values primary symbology area. Knowing java-script programming will help, but for a first expression this task would feel difficult.
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/production/aviation/write-arcade-expressions-for-symbology-and-labeling.htm
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/layer-properties/set-custom-expressions-for-symbology.htm
